# Current slide active on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am implementing the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/x3V6Y/) below on my site, found elsewhere on this forum, but would just like to edit it slightly so that if two slides are sections are visible at any one time the top one rather than the bottom is assigned the 'active' class.

```
$(function() {
  var sections = {},
    _height = $(window).height(),
    i = 0;

  // Grab positions of our sections 
  $('.section').each(function() {
    sections[this.name] = $(this).offset().top;
  });

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var pos = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Look in the sections object and see if any section is viewable on the screen. 
    // If two are viewable, the lower one will be the active one. 
    for (i in sections) {
      if (sections[i] > pos && sections[i] < pos + _height) {
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $('#nav_' + i).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you rewrite/explain this sentence? '..if two slides are sections are visible at any one time the top one rather than the bottom is assigned the 'active' class.'

Comment: he didn't explain it well, but here's how I undestood it:

what he basically wants is that while you scroll down the page, as soon as the next section is visible, update the "active" menu item appropriately.

for example" if section2 is visible while I scroll, make "Section2" active on the left menu.

Comment: sorry my bad, the current setting for the code is that if two sections [slides] are visible simultaneously then the bottom slide is the one that will be assigned the active class, I would like to make the top slide the one assigned the active class. Does that make more sense?

Comment: solved it, after a bit of tinkering, was as simple as changing the greater then and less than symbols but thanks anyway :)